# Application of Baire Category to show a set has non-empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

Suppose $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed with the usual metric, and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, \exists n  \,$ such that $\frac{x}{n} \in X$. I am trying to prove $int(X) \neq \emptyset$.

I tried to proceed by Baire Category theorem, which implies $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be expressed as a countable union of nowhere dense sets.

Write \begin{align}
\mathbb{R} = &\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty}\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{x}{n} \in X \} \\
           = \, &X \, \cup \bigcup_{n = 2}^{\infty}\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{x}{n} \in X \} 
\end{align}

My idea is that if we show each $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{x}{n} \in X \}$ for $n>1$ is nowhere dense, then it would force $int(X) \neq \emptyset$, otherwise Baire Category would not be satisfied.

Now, each $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \frac{x}{n} \in X \}$ is closed, because it clearly contains its limit points. So I just need to check its interior is empty. This is where I am stuck. I am not sure how to justify these sets have no non-empty open sets inside them.

Comment: Well if $X_n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{x}{n}\in X\}$ has an interior point $x_0$, then $nx_0$ will be an interior point for $X$.

Comment: So if $X_n$ is not nowhere dense, then neither is $X$. How does that finish the proof?

Comment: If there exists some $n$ such that $X_n$ has non-empty interior, it follows by what I said that $X$ will have non-empty interior, so you are done. Otherwise all the $X_n$ have empty interior and you can apply the Baire theorem.

Comment: Got it, thank you.